# How to access and display the field in VF email Templates from the junction objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, lookup

I need to display a field in an Visualforce email template.The Field is from a junction object1. Case has a junction object (junction1) which is related to another Junction object(Junction2) thereby related to another object(Object1) which holds the field that has to be displayed.

VF Email template <----- Case <---Junction1<----Junction2 <-----Object1 <--- Field with value to be displayed

{!cx1.Junction2_*r.Object1*_r.Name}
                {!cx.Subject}</td>
                {!cx.Contact.email}</td>
                {!cx.Status}</td>-->

Please advice us with a Solution or sample codes if any.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with standard merged fields in the VF template. You will have to query for that field separately using a custom controller (APEX).

That functionality is described here:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm

You'll need to pass an Id to the controller as input for the query. A code example for that is shown here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000096sUIAQ